# BAD DC transfering FSMO Roles to ADC

Tags: domain-controller

I have a DC (FQDN:server.icmcpk.local) and an ADC (FQDN:file-server.icmcpk.local).
Recently my DC is facing a bad sector problem so I changed the Operation Masters to file-server for all five roles. but when ever i turn off the OLD DC the file-server also stops wroking with AD and GPMC further i m also unable to join any other computer to this domain.

For Test purpose i also added a new ADC (FQDN:wds-server.icmcpk.local) but no succes with the old DC off i had to turn the old DC on and then joined it.

I m attaching the Dcdiags for all three servers.

Kindly help me so that i b able to reinstall new HDD and it can go online again.

```
---------------------------------------
Server
---------------------------------------

C:\Program Files\Support Tools>dcdiag

Domain Controller Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\SERVER
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... SERVER passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\SERVER
      Starting test: Replications
         [Replications Check,SERVER] A recent replication attempt failed:
            From FILE-SERVER to SERVER
            Naming Context: DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=icmcpk,DC=local
            The replication generated an error (1908):
            Could not find the domain controller for this domain.
            The failure occurred at 2012-05-04 14:07:13.
            The last success occurred at 2012-05-04 13:48:39.
            1 failures have occurred since the last success.
            Kerberos Error.
            A KDC was not found to authenticate the call.
            Check that sufficient domain controllers are available.
         [Replications Check,SERVER] A recent replication attempt failed:
            From WDS-SERVER to SERVER
            Naming Context: DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=icmcpk,DC=local
            The replication generated an error (1908):
            Could not find the domain controller for this domain.
            The failure occurred at 2012-05-04 14:07:13.
            The last success occurred at 2012-05-04 13:48:39.
            1 failures have occurred since the last success.
            Kerberos Error.
            A KDC was not found to authenticate the call.
            Check that sufficient domain controllers are available.
         [Replications Check,SERVER] A recent replication attempt failed:
            From FILE-SERVER to SERVER
            Naming Context: DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=icmcpk,DC=local
            The replication generated an error (1908):
            Could not find the domain controller for this domain.
            The failure occurred at 2012-05-04 14:07:13.
            The last success occurred at 2012-05-04 13:48:39.
            1 failures have occurred since the last success.
            Kerberos Error.
            A KDC was not found to authenticate the call.
            Check that sufficient domain controllers are available.
         [Replications Check,SERVER] A recent replication attempt failed:
            From WDS-SERVER to SERVER
            Naming Context: DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=icmcpk,DC=local
            The replication generated an error (1908):
            Could not find the domain controller for this domain.
            The failure occurred at 2012-05-04 14:07:13.
            The last success occurred at 2012-05-04 13:48:39.
            1 failures have occurred since the last success.
            Kerberos Error.
            A KDC was not found to authenticate the call.
            Check that sufficient domain controllers are available.
         [Replications Check,SERVER] A recent replication attempt failed:
            From FILE-SERVER to SERVER
            Naming Context: CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=icmcpk,DC=local
            The replication generated an error (1908):
            Could not find the domain controller for this domain.
            The failure occurred at 2012-05-04 14:07:13.
            The last success occurred at 2012-05-04 13:48:39.
            1 failures have occurred since the last success.
            Kerberos Error.
            A KDC was not found to authenticate the call.
            Check that sufficient domain controllers are available.
         [Replications Check,SERVER] A recent replication attempt failed:
            From WDS-SERVER to SERVER
            Naming Context: CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=icmcpk,DC=local
            The replication generated an error (1908):
            Could not find the domain controller for this domain.
            The failure occurred at 2012-05-04 14:07:13.
            The last success occurred at 2012-05-04 13:48:39.
            1 failures have occurred since the last success.
            Kerberos Error.
            A KDC was not found to authenticate the call.
            Check that sufficient domain controllers are available.
         [Replications Check,SERVER] A recent replication attempt failed:
            From WDS-SERVER to SERVER
            Naming Context: DC=icmcpk,DC=local
            The replication generated an error (1908):
            Could not find the domain controller for this domain.
            The failure occurred at 2012-05-04 14:07:13.
            The last success occurred at 2012-05-04 13:48:39.
            1 failures have occurred since the last success.
            Kerberos Error.
            A KDC was not found to authenticate the call.
            Check that sufficient domain controllers are available.
         ......................... SERVER passed test Replications
      Starting test: NCSecDesc
         ......................... SERVER passed test NCSecDesc
      Starting test: NetLogons
         ......................... SERVER passed test NetLogons
      Starting test: Advertising
         ......................... SERVER passed test Advertising
      Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders
         ......................... SERVER passed test KnowsOfRoleHolders
      Starting test: RidManager
         ......................... SERVER passed test RidManager
      Starting test: MachineAccount
         ......................... SERVER passed test MachineAccount
      Starting test: Services
         ......................... SERVER passed test Services
      Starting test: ObjectsReplicated
         ......................... SERVER passed test ObjectsReplicated
      Starting test: frssysvol
         ......................... SERVER passed test frssysvol
      Starting test: frsevent
         There are warning or error events within the last 24 hours after the
         SYSVOL has been shared.  Failing SYSVOL replication problems may cause
         Group Policy problems.
         ......................... SERVER failed test frsevent
      Starting test: kccevent
         ......................... SERVER passed test kccevent
      Starting test: systemlog
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0x80001778
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:05:39
            Event String: The previous system shutdown at 1:26:31 PM on
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0x825A0011
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:07:45
            (Event String could not be retrieved)
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0x00000457
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:13:40
            (Event String could not be retrieved)
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0x00000457
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:14:25
            (Event String could not be retrieved)
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0x00000457
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:14:25
            (Event String could not be retrieved)
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0x00000457
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:14:38
            (Event String could not be retrieved)
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0xC1010020
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:16:14
            Event String: Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC80.MFCLOC could
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0xC101003B
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:16:14
            Event String: Resolve Partial Assembly failed for
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0xC101003B
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:16:14
            Event String: Generate Activation Context failed for
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0xC1010020
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:16:14
            Event String: Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC80.MFCLOC could
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0xC101003B
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:16:14
            Event String: Resolve Partial Assembly failed for
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0xC101003B
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:16:14
            Event String: Generate Activation Context failed for
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0x825A0011
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:22:57
            (Event String could not be retrieved)
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0xC1010020
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:22:59
            Event String: Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC80.MFCLOC could
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0xC101003B
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:22:59
            Event String: Resolve Partial Assembly failed for
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0xC101003B
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:22:59
            Event String: Generate Activation Context failed for
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0xC1010020
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:22:59
            Event String: Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC80.MFCLOC could
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0xC101003B
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:22:59
            Event String: Resolve Partial Assembly failed for
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0xC101003B
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:22:59
            Event String: Generate Activation Context failed for
         ......................... SERVER failed test systemlog
      Starting test: VerifyReferences
         ......................... SERVER passed test VerifyReferences

   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation

      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom

   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation

      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom

   Running partition tests on : Schema
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom

   Running partition tests on : Configuration
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom

   Running partition tests on : icmcpk
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... icmcpk passed test CrossRefValidation
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... icmcpk passed test CheckSDRefDom

   Running enterprise tests on : icmcpk.local
      Starting test: Intersite
         ......................... icmcpk.local passed test Intersite
      Starting test: FsmoCheck
         ......................... icmcpk.local passed test FsmoCheck

----------------------
File-Server
----------------------
C:\Users\Administrator.ICMCPK>dcdiag

Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = FILE-SERVER
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\FILE-SERVER
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... FILE-SERVER passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\FILE-SERVER
      Starting test: Advertising
         Warning: DsGetDcName returned information for \\Server.icmcpk.local,
         when we were trying to reach FILE-SERVER.
         SERVER IS NOT RESPONDING or IS NOT CONSIDERED SUITABLE.
         ......................... FILE-SERVER failed test Advertising
      Starting test: FrsEvent
         ......................... FILE-SERVER passed test FrsEvent
      Starting test: DFSREvent
         ......................... FILE-SERVER passed test DFSREvent
      Starting test: SysVolCheck
         ......................... FILE-SERVER passed test SysVolCheck
      Starting test: KccEvent
         ......................... FILE-SERVER passed test KccEvent
      Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders
         ......................... FILE-SERVER passed test KnowsOfRoleHolders
      Starting test: MachineAccount
         ......................... FILE-SERVER passed test MachineAccount
      Starting test: NCSecDesc
         Error NT AUTHORITY\ENTERPRISE DOMAIN CONTROLLERS doesn't have
            Replicating Directory Changes In Filtered Set
         access rights for the naming context:
         DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=icmcpk,DC=local
         Error NT AUTHORITY\ENTERPRISE DOMAIN CONTROLLERS doesn't have
            Replicating Directory Changes In Filtered Set
         access rights for the naming context:
         DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=icmcpk,DC=local
         ......................... FILE-SERVER failed test NCSecDesc
      Starting test: NetLogons
         Unable to connect to the NETLOGON share! (\\FILE-SERVER\netlogon)
         [FILE-SERVER] An net use or LsaPolicy operation failed with error 67,
         The network name cannot be found..
         ......................... FILE-SERVER failed test NetLogons
      Starting test: ObjectsReplicated
         ......................... FILE-SERVER passed test ObjectsReplicated
      Starting test: Replications
         ......................... FILE-SERVER passed test Replications
      Starting test: RidManager
         ......................... FILE-SERVER passed test RidManager
      Starting test: Services
         ......................... FILE-SERVER passed test Services
      Starting test: SystemLog
         An Error Event occurred.  EventID: 0x00000469
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:01:10
            Event String:
            The processing of Group Policy failed because of lack of network con
nectivity to a domain controller. This may be a transient condition. A success m
essage would be generated once the machine gets connected to the domain controll
er and Group Policy has succesfully processed. If you do not see a success messa
ge for several hours, then contact your administrator.
         An Warning Event occurred.  EventID: 0x8000A001
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:07:11
            Event String:
            The Security System could not establish a secured connection with th
e server ldap/icmcpk.local/icmcpk.local@ICMCPK.LOCAL. No authentication protocol
 was available.
         An Warning Event occurred.  EventID: 0x00000BBC
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:30:34
            Event String:
            Windows Defender Real-Time Protection agent has detected changes. Mi
crosoft recommends you analyze the software that made these changes for potentia
l risks. You can use information about how these programs operate to choose whet
her to allow them to run or remove them from your computer.  Allow changes only
if you trust the program or the software publisher. Windows Defender can't undo
changes that you allow.
         An Warning Event occurred.  EventID: 0x00000BBC
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:30:36
            Event String:
            Windows Defender Real-Time Protection agent has detected changes. Mi
crosoft recommends you analyze the software that made these changes for potentia
l risks. You can use information about how these programs operate to choose whet
her to allow them to run or remove them from your computer.  Allow changes only
if you trust the program or the software publisher. Windows Defender can't undo
changes that you allow.
         ......................... FILE-SERVER failed test SystemLog
      Starting test: VerifyReferences
         ......................... FILE-SERVER passed test VerifyReferences


   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test
         CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test
         CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Schema
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Configuration
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : icmcpk
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... icmcpk passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... icmcpk passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running enterprise tests on : icmcpk.local
      Starting test: LocatorCheck
         ......................... icmcpk.local passed test LocatorCheck
      Starting test: Intersite
         ......................... icmcpk.local passed test Intersite

---------------------
WDS-Server
---------------------
C:\Users\Administrator.ICMCPK>dcdiag

Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = WDS-SERVER
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\WDS-SERVER
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... WDS-SERVER passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\WDS-SERVER
      Starting test: Advertising
         Warning: DsGetDcName returned information for \\Server.icmcpk.local,
         when we were trying to reach WDS-SERVER.
         SERVER IS NOT RESPONDING or IS NOT CONSIDERED SUITABLE.
         ......................... WDS-SERVER failed test Advertising
      Starting test: FrsEvent
         There are warning or error events within the last 24 hours after the
         SYSVOL has been shared.  Failing SYSVOL replication problems may cause
         Group Policy problems.
         ......................... WDS-SERVER passed test FrsEvent
      Starting test: DFSREvent
         ......................... WDS-SERVER passed test DFSREvent
      Starting test: SysVolCheck
         ......................... WDS-SERVER passed test SysVolCheck
      Starting test: KccEvent
         ......................... WDS-SERVER passed test KccEvent
      Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders
         ......................... WDS-SERVER passed test KnowsOfRoleHolders
      Starting test: MachineAccount
         ......................... WDS-SERVER passed test MachineAccount
      Starting test: NCSecDesc
         Error NT AUTHORITY\ENTERPRISE DOMAIN CONTROLLERS doesn't have
            Replicating Directory Changes In Filtered Set
         access rights for the naming context:
         DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=icmcpk,DC=local
         Error NT AUTHORITY\ENTERPRISE DOMAIN CONTROLLERS doesn't have
            Replicating Directory Changes In Filtered Set
         access rights for the naming context:
         DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=icmcpk,DC=local
         ......................... WDS-SERVER failed test NCSecDesc
      Starting test: NetLogons
         Unable to connect to the NETLOGON share! (\\WDS-SERVER\netlogon)
         [WDS-SERVER] An net use or LsaPolicy operation failed with error 67,
         The network name cannot be found..
         ......................... WDS-SERVER failed test NetLogons
      Starting test: ObjectsReplicated
         ......................... WDS-SERVER passed test ObjectsReplicated
      Starting test: Replications
         ......................... WDS-SERVER passed test Replications
      Starting test: RidManager
         ......................... WDS-SERVER passed test RidManager
      Starting test: Services
         ......................... WDS-SERVER passed test Services
      Starting test: SystemLog
         An Error Event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000041E
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:02:55
            Event String:
            The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not obtain the
name of a domain controller. This could be caused by a name resolution failure.
Verify your Domain Name Sysytem (DNS) is configured and working correctly.
         An Error Event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000041E
            Time Generated: 05/04/2012   14:08:33
            Event String:
            The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not obtain the
name of a domain controller. This could be caused by a name resolution failure.
Verify your Domain Name Sysytem (DNS) is configured and working correctly.
         ......................... WDS-SERVER failed test SystemLog
      Starting test: VerifyReferences
         ......................... WDS-SERVER passed test VerifyReferences


   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test
         CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test
         CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Schema
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Configuration
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : icmcpk
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... icmcpk passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... icmcpk passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running enterprise tests on : icmcpk.local
      Starting test: LocatorCheck
         ......................... icmcpk.local passed test LocatorCheck
      Starting test: Intersite
         ......................... icmcpk.local passed test Intersite
```

Comment: What exactly is an ADC?

Comment: Probably should check to see who has a Global Catalog, too

Comment: @charlesbridge I'd hope that they all hold a copy of the global catalog. The only time it makes sense for a DC to *not* hold a copy of the GC is when the Infrastructure Master needs to function as-expected in a multi-forest/multi-domain situation. In this the server holding the IM role for the forest shouldn't be a GC holder. In all other cases, there's usually not a good reason to leave it off.

Comment: True MDMarra, but it's not a default for some reason.  Someone has to check off the GC box on the DC after a dcpromo.

Comment: It's checked by default in 2008 and later. I'm not sure of OSes earlier than that.

Answer (score 5):

If I had to guess, I would say that you probably have a screwed up DNS infrastructure.

The easiest thing to do is run DNS on all three Domain Controllers. Have 127.0.0.1 be the last entry in the list for each DC and have the other two DCs listed ahead of it.

Make sure that your clients are configured to use at least two of these, preferably more.

Comment: +1 It's always a DNS issue.

Comment: ok here are some more details

Comment: ok both @MDMarra and charlesbridge here are some more details:<br/> only Server is running MS Server2k3 remaining both File-server and WDS-server are running MS Server2k8 and all three servers have global catalog. <br/>for the DNS the Server and File-server both are configured as primary DNS servers but the WDS-server is configured as the secondary DNS server.<br/> Any tip on how check the DNS?[tag:DNS]

Comment: @mdmarra an ADC means (Additional Domain Controller)

Comment: There is no such thing as an Additional Domain Controller. They're all peers. I also have no idea what you mean by our comment about your DNS configuration.

Comment: sorry i misunderstood the DNS! So where can in start troubleshooting?

Comment: and DNS are configured as you suggested above!

Comment: So each domain controller is configured to use each other before itself? You should update your question with the IP/DNS settings for the network adapters in each domain controller.

Answer (score 0):

The ForestDNSZones and DomainDNSZones both have their own FSMO Role Holders that were most likely on the Old DC as well.  Please see the article here: http://msmvps.com/blogs/ulfbsimonweidner/archive/2008/07/31/how-many-infrastructure-masters-do-you-have.aspx

Also this KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949257